# pdflatex with index suddenly fails with undefined control sequences

Tags: pdftex, errors, indexing

The document I have been working on has built the index fine in the past. I have since made some changes to Part and Chapters, and re-arranged things in the preamble a little. Now pdflatex, mkindex, pdflatex fails with the following error:

```
Undefined control sequence. l.3  \makeatletter\scan@allowedfalse
Undefined control sequence. l.6   \item Acceptance set\pfill
Undefined control sequence. l.7 ...cceptance setand demand for insurance\pfill
```

I am using the index package as so in my preamble (I have tried moving it around heaps with no effect)

the preamble is here:
http://pastebin.com/ng47YuZh

TIA

Comment: There is probable some index item that contains something wrong. Check all your `\index`, remove any `.ind` and `.idx` files and try again.

Comment: It seems that this is a problem with my texlive install (Ubuntu 11.04). The index fails with even the simplest document 8(

Comment: Why don't you show such a simple document? Your example does not compile (it has no text and depends on tcilatex and other files not in general distribution).

Comment: http://pastebin.com/hhdaHWWB

Comment: It doesn't fail on my machine; what's the error on yours?

Comment: ! Undefined control sequence.
l.3  \makeatletter\scan@allowedfalse
! Undefined control sequence.
l.6   \item Anothe enty\pfill
! Undefined control sequence.
l.11   \item Oh no an index entry\pfill

Comment: You should mention also the Makeindex style you are using.

Comment: sorry, I am unsure what you mean, unless you mean that i am using the makeindex that acompanies the index package. (At least I think I am). This was all working not so long ago, thats what really gets me.

Comment: There's no "makeindex that accompanies the index package". You are calling makeindex with some option, such as `makeindex -s bbind`; what's the option you are using? Because that's responsible for adding those "undefined control sequences".

Comment: @Jasper: Rather than "answering" your question, you should edit your original question to include the additional information. (You may have to register at tex.se to do so.)

Comment: I have never called makeindex with any options, indeed with -s bbind does cause undefined control sequences. My bad, the index package modifies \makeindex, not makeindex. What options should I include such that this will again work properly? I feel like a total n00b again.

Comment: Indexing requires a three-step procedure: (1) a LaTeX run on `jasper.tex` writes out a file `jasper.idx`; (2) a `makeindex jasper` writes the file `jasper.ind`; (3) a LaTeX run on `jasper.tex` also reads `jasper.ind`. A simple `makeindex jasper` won't add any `\makeatletter\scan@allowed` command into the `.ind` file, so there's something you are doing that you have to tell us.

Comment: sorry I thought I had this in my question. Yes I am running pdflatex in this fashion. i) pdflatex blah ii) makeindex blah iii) pdflatex blah (this is where I get the errors on the second pdflatex). I have deleted all other files except blah.tex, to be sure... still the same.

Comment: What front-end are you using? Look into its settings and see what options it passes to makeindex

Comment: I usually use kile. I am running all this from bash, command line. not through kile.

Comment: In this case the sequence `rm jasper.ind && pdflatex jasper && makeindex jasper && pdflatex` should produce no error.

Comment: @Jasper: please edit your question or add a comment to provide more information. The answer section is only for solutions. Please consider registering yourself. The site might not recognize you on your return otherwise and create a different user with the same name and icon. I merge the one created by the "answer" to the account of the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find the same problem, my mistake was to use `mkindex` instead of `makeindex`. 
Using `makeindex` solve the problem.